# Finding RNA Loops

Tags: bioinformatics, rna, structure-prediction

I was rooting through the literature, but there is too much work on the topic of detecting loops in RNA and the RNA helices that go with them.  Can anyone point to a good review on this topic or even better describe some better performing algorithms?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by loops? Just unstructured parts of the RNA (= not in any base pairs)?

Comment: A loop in this case would be the result of an RNA helix from a single stranded RNA.  The loop would be the result of the strand forming a helix by itself.

Comment: So you only need to find the helices, from there identifying  the loops is trivial. Can the loops have interactions with other parts of the RNA, e.g. pseudoknots? If not, any secondary structure prediction program like mfold should suit your purpose.

Comment: just looking for helices.  i wasn't aware that was trivial.. is mfold accurate?

Comment: as @MadScientist said mfold or RNAfold(Vienna) should work for secondary structure prediction. Anything flanked by a half-stem should be a loop. Both mfold and RNAfold have a limit on the size of the sequence. They don't take large sequences and splitting the sequence is not a great option because the local MFE may be different from the global one. There is also an experimental technique called [PARS](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v467/n7311/full/nature09322.html) in which the RNA is digested with different RNAses (V1, S1) and base-paired regions are identified by sequencing

Comment: Recently sequencing approach has been extended to obtain RNA secondary structures [in-vivo](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/vaop/ncurrent/full/nature12756.html) by using a soluble RNA-methylating agent (DMS).

Comment: EDIT: Anything flanked by a half-stem (which pair with each other) should be a loop

Comment: any reviews?  the last time i looked this was not a completely solved problem.

Comment: As an improvement to what @WYSIWYG mentioned, PARS is fairly low resolution since it is still enzyme based. The newer in vivo SHAPE or DMS-seq methods are much better and more informative.

Answer (score 2):

I frankly don't trust Mfold or RNAfold for finding structure. There are just too many false positives and without experimental verification, it's not reliable. For finding hypothetical local structure, it's great. However to find evolutionary conserved structure MSA methods like what has been used with Rfam are a more suitable way.

Since you asked for Reviews, any of Sean Eddy's Rfam updates are good. I also suggest checking out https://www.mendeley.com/groups/545791/rna-structure/.

But for now, I think [Revolutions in RNA Secondary Structure Prediction](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16500677) by David Mathews who developed the Turner rules and Mfold is a good start.